# How do I find the area between two polar curves?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, plotting

More specifically above r=6 and below r=4+4cos(θ)

graph of the two curves

```
PolarPlot[{6, 4 + 4 Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Comment: `Area` will help you

Comment: There are 3 possibilities.

Answer (score 6):

```
 Integrate[Max[0, (4 + 4 Cos[t])^2/2 - 6^2/2 ], {t, -Pi, Pi}]
```

or

```
 Integrate[(4 + 4 Cos[t])^2/2 - 6^2/2 , {t, -Pi/3, Pi/3}]
```

> 18 Sqrt[3] - 4 Pi

Edit: another approach:

```
 Area[{r Sin[t], r Cos[t]}, {t, -Pi, Pi}, {r, 6, Max[6, 4 + 4 Cos[t]]}]
```

or

```
 Area[CoordinateTransform[ "Polar" -> "Cartesian", {r, t}],
                         {t, -Pi, Pi}, {r, 6, Max[6, 4 + 4 Cos[t]]}]
```

> 2 (9 Sqrt[3] - 2 Pi)

Comment: This is a much better way to do it than mucking about with the `Area` function (IMHO).  Just to elaborate on it a bit:  in polar coordinates, the area of a wedge bounded by the function $r(\theta)$ is $\frac{1}{2} \int r^2(\theta) d \theta$.

Comment: Plus, it gives on a result (on my machine) in 0.06 seconds, compared to 16.8 seconds for the `Area` method.  A little thought ahead of time results in a speed-up by a factor of over 250.  :-)

Answer (score 5):

As HyperGroups suggests, we can take advantage of the `Area` function new in v10.

First, we'll represent the region implicitly.  We want:

$$
6 < r < 4 + 4\cos\theta \\
6 < \sqrt{x^2+y^2} < 4 + 4\cos\arctan\frac y x
$$

First we'll plot this region to make sure we're correct:

```
Show[
 RegionPlot[6 < Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 4 + 4 Cos[ArcTan[x, y]], {x, -8, 8}, {y, -8, 8}]
 PolarPlot[{6, 4 + 4 Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
]
```

[image]

Now we can represent this as an `ImplicitRegion`:

```
region = ImplicitRegion[6 < Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 4 + 4 Cos[ArcTan[x, y]], {x, y}];
```

And finally we can compute the area:

```
area = Area[region];
```

This takes 20 seconds on my laptop, and produces a pretty nasty expression.  In order to simplify it I had to do:

```
FullSimplify @ ComplexExpand @ ToRadicals @ FullSimplify[area]
(* 18 Sqrt[3] - 4 π *)
```

Comment: I have 10.1 on OS X and your `Area[region]` gives the message `Area::nmet: Unable to compute the area of region ImplicitRegion[...]`.

Comment: @StephenLuttrell I get a (long) answer on 10.0.0.0, Windows 8.1 64-bit

Comment: @Stephen You can always solve it the "easy" way: `Reduce[6 < 4 + 4 Cos[\[Theta]] && -Pi < \[Theta] < Pi, {\[Theta]}]` then `Integrate[r, {\[Theta], -Pi/3, Pi/3}, {r, 6, 4 + 4 Cos[\[Theta]]}]`

Comment: On my machine with 10.0.2, 2012rcampion's `Area[region]` works fine.

Comment: @Stephen How about if we define the region parametrically? `region = ParametricRegion[{{r Cos[\[Theta]], r Sin[\[Theta]]}, 
  6 < r < 4 + 4 Cos[\[Theta]]}, {{\[Theta], -Pi, +Pi}, {r, 0, 8}}]` works for me

Comment: By the way, just `FullSimplify[area]` already gives `18 Sqrt[3] - 4 π` (on 10.0.2 here).

Comment: @Taiki Interesting, it gives me an expression involving `I Log[Root[___]]`, with two roots of an 8th power polynomial.

Comment: @2012rcampion if I slightly modify this region say `Area[ImplicitRegion[
   6 < Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 4 + 4 Cos[ArcTan[x, y] && x < 7 ], {x, y}]]` (Try it with `Show`) even with MMA 10.2 I'm back to the error message `Area::nmet: Unable to compute the area of region Imp...`. It beats me your solution cannot be generalized even after 3 successive MMA versions since this new function has been announced!

Answer (score 3):

We can use any one of the line integrals that by Green's Theorem yield the area:

```
dA = RandomChoice[{x Dt[y], -y Dt[x], (x Dt[y] - y Dt[x])/2}]
param = {x -> r Cos[θ], y -> r Sin[θ]};
boundary1 = {r -> 6};
boundary2 = {r -> 4 + 4 Cos[θ]};
θ0 = θ /. Solve[{Equal @@ (r /. {boundary1, boundary2}), -Pi < θ <  Pi}, {θ}];
Integrate[dA /. param /. boundary2 /. Dt[θ] -> 1, Flatten[{θ, θ0}]] -
 Integrate[dA /. param /. boundary1 /. Dt[θ] -> 1, Flatten[{θ, θ0}]] // Simplify
(*
  1/2 (-y Dt[x] + x Dt[y])

  18 Sqrt[3] - 4 π
*)
```

---

Now this is an interesting <s>bug</s> **result** (the double integral in polar coordinates):

```
Integrate[r, {r, θ} ∈ ImplicitRegion[6 <= r <= 4 + 4 Cos[θ], {r, θ}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As [Michael Siefert](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/27813/michael-seifert) astutely pointed out, the problem is that the range of `θ` is assumed to be all reals.  Restricting `θ` to one period of length `2 Pi` gives the right answer:

```
Integrate[r, {r, θ} ∈ ImplicitRegion[6 <= r <= 4 + 4 Cos[θ] && 0 <= θ <= 2 Pi, {r, θ}]]
(*  2 (9 Sqrt[3] - 2 π)  *)
```

Comment: Not really a bug;  Mathematica doesn't "know" that the natural range of $\theta$ is from -π to π without you providing that context.  So it gives you an infinite sum of integrals, corresponding to the regions $\theta = [-\pi/3, \pi/3], \theta = [5\pi/3, 7\pi/3], \theta = [11\pi/3, 13\pi/3]$, and so on.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Ah, I see.  I didn't think of that.  Thanks.  I suppose it's a "smart" answer, in that it could have said it diverges.